# PHP - show user id in url

Tags: php, session, profile, userid

I wanna be able to show userid in url, like this: profile.php?user=1, 2 etc.

I've been searching everywhere, but I can't get it to work.

profile.php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';


 // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $id = $_GET['userId'];

?>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : $_SESSION['id'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = $id";
 // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
 header("Location:profile.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user']);
 exit;
 }
// select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $id = $_GET['userId'];
?>


<?php echo $userRow['userId'];?>
```

I use that last command there to link to my own profile, but I wanna know how to view other users profiles.

Comment: $_GET will read the parameter, not put it there. You have to put it there manually, means when you're doing a href in your html code you should do something like `href="domain.com/profile.php?user=$variable"`. For `$variable` you should read the value from SQL.

Comment: $id = $_GET['userId']; is for getting GET parameter not setting it

Comment: You want to add $id in Location: index.php like Location: index.php?uid=$id;

Comment: I have one questions, for security, it's best practice or good to show URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are setting the $_SESSION['user'] on successfully login, then you direct the user to the profile.php page using the header, what you need to do now u need to change your header to look like:

```
<?php


header("Location:profile.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user']);

?>
```

That will direct the user to profile.php?use=1 if id is one then when ever you are linking back to profile.php from your dashboard using the anchor it must look like:

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>">profile</a>
```

> NB: For your own benefit don't use mysql_ the function is depreciated
>   and removed from php 7. use mysqli instead,
>
> Then for your own data security use prepared statements, with mysqli
>   or pdo

Comment: this worked to get the user id in the url, but is there a way I could be able to view other profiles by changing the number in the url? from id=2 to id=1 f.eks

Comment: this works for the current logged in user, if you would view other user's profile as another user lets say admin, you would then `<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['userid'];?>">profile</a>`

I will edit my answer for more

Answer (score 0):

**So basically you want to show id in url or want to pass id from url**

if you want to pass id using url than :

use

```
<a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

And you cant get that data using `$_GET[user];`

SO please clarify that what you want.?

Answer (score 0):

i would do like this:

```
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit;
 }
 elseif ( isset($_SESSION['user'] && !$_GET['user']){
   header("Location: profile.php?user=" . $_SESSION['user']);
 }
 else{
   // select loggedin users detail
   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
   $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
   $id = $_GET['userId'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the userid to the url if your using form:

```
<form="profile.php?=user<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

And just in case you want to pass it on other page so you can use it there here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['nameofsubmitbutton']))
{

$Sample = $_POST['nameoffield'];
header("Location: nextpage.php?id=$Sample");
}
```